# Custom Login Component - Redirecting depends from entered data

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, login, custom-component, redirect

I'm administratior of several sites and have exp. with Joomla over 4 years, mostly worked with creating websites with this great builder using different modules, but haven't a lot exp. with PHP. Recently I got a task: create "login form" (2 fields and button "OK"), with allows user to be redirected to custom page. For example:

```
userId1, userNumb1 -> redirect to http://static/some1
userId2, userNumb2 -> redirect to http://static/another2
```

But I can't find module for this and havent clue how I can do this - my exp. with PHP isn't enough for rewriting mod_mogin.
Can anyone bring me some tips on how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to customise the login form, or is the regular login form already fine?  In other words, are you modifying the authentication process, or is this just username and password?  To redirect on login depending on the user details you'll need a user plugin - but this may not be what you want depending on the answers to the previous question...

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of extensions where unique redirects can be set up for each user:

1. The Pro version of [Redirect on Login](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/redirect-on-login)
2. [Redirect after Login](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/redirect-after-login) (paid extension)